# Arduino: moving light repeating sequence

Tags: arduino, sequence, repeat, led

during shutdown of school my son got some homework to do.

One is programming a moving light sequence, 5 led, which should run:

1, 1-2, 1-2-3, 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3-4-5, 1, 1-2, ...

He is only allowed to use a limited choice of orders, no 'if' or 'while'

The result at the moment is:

1, 1-2, 1-2-3, 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3-4-5, **1-2-3-4-5**, 1, 1-2, ...

Here's the code:

```
void setup() { 

 for (int a=1; a<6; a++) {  
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);     
 } 
} 
void loop() {
 for (int a=1; a<6; a++) {
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(a,LOW);
  delay(300);
 for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
   digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
   delay(300); 
   digitalWrite(b,LOW);
   delay(300);
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks

Markus

Edit: Strange, seems like 'Hi' and 'hallo' aren't allowed to start the post with :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, read through the instruction booklet from school...

```
void setup() { 
for (int a=1; a<6; a++) {  
pinMode(a, OUTPUT);     
} 
} 
void loop() {
for (int a=1; a<6; a++) {
for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
delay(300); 
digitalWrite(b,LOW);
delay(300);
}
}
}
```

Don't know how to name it correctly in English, but it was the double "digital write" (digitalwrite(a,..); digitalwrite(b,..)) in the loop sequence

Answer (score 0):

A simple writing to paper helps (that what the kids should probably learn)

```
for (int a=1; a<6; a++) {
```

Now we have to check what a = ?? Guess what 6
so the next for

for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {

has one extra step, so the condition should imho be

b < a

To debug it helps to use

```
Serial.println("Value of a: ");
Serial.print(a);
Serial.print("  Value of b: ");
Serial.print(b);
```

If it worked please mark as solved

Comment: Didn't work. If he added


for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
b < a;


there's no change.
If he replaces 


b<=a with b<a


he has the sequence:


1,  -2. 1- -3, 1-2- -4, 1-2-3- - 5, 1-2-3-4-  , 1, -2, 1- - 3 ,...


Thx for trying :-)